# http working https not working in facebook

Tags: facebook, https

I'm having a app in FB , it working in http url fine , but it's not working in https url ,

http://www.facebook.com/testappisha/app_453043998071644

https://www.facebook.com/testappisha/app_453043998071644

I can load https live coding mode in normal browser but it not loading inside the facebook , if any one can help me ?

Comment: actually it doesnt work both.

Comment: Since both version of your page load OK – it’s maybe just the app settings? Check if you made a mistake there in setting the correct paths.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/testappisha/app_453043998071644  this url not working friends , check this in this page i can see only empty page

Comment: @user1690703 I think if you use the canvas page url http://apps.facebook.com/testappisha it will work. This will first ask you to accept permissions for the app and then you are redirected correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your app settings. I think the Page Tab URL is not exist. The "pagelet_app_runner" div element must contain an iframe with your code in, but in your pagetab it is empty.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Yes, it is working. Maybe something wrong in your "index.php" when it is deciding which htm file to load. (likedpage.htm or notlikedpage.htm).